# Does rogue's vest bonus damage apply separately for each precision damage source?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, sneak-attack

*Rogue's vest* (MiC 130) grants users with "the skirmish, sneak attack, or sudden strike ability" an extra 1d6 damage "when making such an attack"

Does this mean that, for example, a scout 1/rogue 1/ninja 1 that moves 10 feet and attacks a flat-footed opponent (who lacks uncanny dodge) deals 1d6 base skirmish damage plus 1d6 extra damage because they made "such an attack", as well as 1d6 base sneak attack damage plus 1d6 extra damage for making "such an attack" and 1d6 base sudden strike damage plus 1d6 extra...For a total of 6d6 precision damage? Or is the "attack" only granted the item's bonus damage once, for a total of 4d6 precision damage?

Answer (score -2):

No.

This item would only increase the sneak attack damage once. This is because all sneak attack abilities are applied to the same pool. There are no separate pools of sneak attack.

Comment: _Complete Adventurer_ says something like this about sudden strike and sneak attack, though I think it is only in the context of requirements. So far as I know, nothing says anything like this for skirmish. This answer is, I believe, incorrect, but even if correct that needs citation.